# mod pagespeed domain sharding

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to shard a domain but it seems to work find for maybe at most 30 minutes then all the images become broken and i see all these errors:

> Resource based on URL/image.png but cannot access the original
>   Fetch failed for URL/image.pagespeed.png, status=404

here are my settings:

> ModPagespeedDomain URL
>   ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain localhost/URL *URL
>   ModPagespeedShardDomain URL shard1.URL,shard2.URL
>   ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain URL www.URL

i've tried several different configs but can't seem to get it right.

i have several sites then they each have their own folder

> /var/www/site1/
>   /var/www/site2/
>   /var/www/site3/

any help would be greatly appreciated!